# Python 2.7 print vs return

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to grab every other letter from a string but i'm having some problem with print and return.
Why when i use print, the output is what i want and when i use return i only get the first letter?

```
string_bits(Hello)  # Return string made of every other char starting with the first

def string_bits(str):
    x = len(str)
    for i in range(0,x,2):
        print str[i]

output: H
        l
        o
```

vs

```
def string_bits(str):
    x = len(str)
    for i in range(0,x,2):
        return str[i]

output: H
```

Comment: `return` returns from your function. So the rest of the loop will not be executed.

Comment: `return` terminates the function! You could use `yield` with a little refactoring

Comment: you want this to be recursive so you won't want return in your loop as it will terminate the loop / escape the function

Comment: Since strings are iterable, you can save yourself a lot of work with slicing: ``print( "Hello"[::2] )``. And please do not name your variable ``str``, it will shadow the built-in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone has pointed out, your function returns the instance on the first loop. You can use a temporary variable to store your result and return that result.

You can use the statement below inside a function:

```
return ''.join([ur_string[i] for i in range(0, len(ur_string), 2)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you want is this:

```
def string_bits(the_str):
    x = len(the_str)
    for i in range(0,x,2):
        yield the_str[i]
```

or `the_str[::2]` takes only `even` position character

Answer (score 0):

#### function 1

Here, you loop over the whole string and print each letter. The loop finishes when there are no more letters, and the function exits.

```
def string_bits(str):
    x = len(str)
    for i in range(0,x,2):
        print str[i]
```

#### function 2

```
def string_bits(str):
    x = len(str)
    for i in range(0,x,2):
        return str[i]
```

Here, you loop over the whole string, but instead of printing `str[i]` you are returning it. The `return` causes your function to exit, and so the loop doesn't continue on to the other letters.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you `return`, the program exits the function, whereas using `print` the program continues the loop.

As strings are iterable, you can use slicing to get the characters you want by specifying the step as 2:

To return a string:

```
def string_bits(s):
    return s[::2]
```

To return a list of characters:

```
def string_bits(s):    
    return list(s[::2])
```

Alternatively, you could use [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-yield_stmt) to create a generator:

```
def string_bits(s):
    for char in s[::2]:
        yield char
```