# Recursive function not returning anything. What is the problem?

Tags: python, recursion

I am writing a recursive function that will eliminate the letter from the string until it will become empty:

```
def recur_partial(text):
    #base case
    if (len(text) < 2):
        print('')
    #recursive case
    else:
        text = text[1:]
        return recur_partial(text)
```

For example:

```
>>> recur_partial('text')
```

expected output:

```
ext
xt
t
```

my output:

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49068903/python-2-7-print-vs-return, given the confusion between printing a value and returning a value.

Answer (score 2):

I had a few observations that are important for you to understand recursion properly:

**Recursive functions return one value**

Your expectation is not correct because it assumes the function will return multiple values.
While it does iterate and go over the same code multiple times, it returns only one value at the end.

**In the base case you have no return statement**

You wrote a good recursive function that does have a base part and doesn't cause a stack overflow, but you do not return anything in the end.

Your function returns nothing since there is not return in the base part, it will always return nothing regardless of the input.

**Recursive function output should change for different inputs**

Regarding the idea, if a recursive function removes one letter every time then the end result will always be an empty string, it wouldn't be a very useful function since the result is the same every time.

This will achieve what you are expecting, but keep in mind it is just printing intermediate results and at the end it return empty string every time.

```
def recur_partial(text):
    #base case
    if (len(text) < 2):
        return '' # changed from print
    #recursive case
    else:
        text = text[1:]
        print(text) # print the value then continue recursion.
        return recur_partial(text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working on idle, but it is outputing nothing in assignment page, where I submitted this code. I think the problem is in there

Comment: This means that anything printed to stdout is not accounted for in the assignment, this is common because printing is considered to be used for debugging only but not as the output of the program.

Answer (score 0):

your exit point of function don't have return statement, so it will return None, put return statement as below

```py
def recur_partial(text):
    #base part
    if (len(text) < 2):
        print('')
        return "put your return statement here"
    #recursive part
    else:
        text = text[1:]
        return recur_partial(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

the `return` isn't a `print`, to see the output you need to insert a print

```
text = text[1:]
print(text)
return recur_partial(text)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this one. It is working on idle. But it is not working on my assignment page. It is not passing evaluation, cause no output. And I thought maybe i've done something wrong

Comment: if you are using the PyCharm as IDLE, try to use the debuging, else you can try to use the pdb. What's the message IDLE return?

Comment: I am using IDLE(Python 3.7). There everything working fine. I think the problem is in online editor.

Comment: try to install the pycharm community edition, it will help you tu see the line with problems, and insert pep8 in you project

Answer (score 0):

You said the problem:

> eliminate the letter from the string until it will become an empty

Your code is looping until `len(text) == 1` (last loop), then return `None`.

Otherwise, you only `print` when `len(text) < 2`, so it's normal it doesn't print anything other an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

Print in every recursive case and change base case to 1

```
def recur_partial(text):
    #base part
    if (len(text) < 1):
        print('')
    #recursive part
    else:
        text = text[1:]
        print(text)
        return recur_partial(text)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this one. It is working on idle. But it is not working on my assignment page. It is not passing evaluation, cause no output. And I thought maybe i've done something wrong

Answer (score 0):

`return` is not a print statement. And set the base case to 1.

The code below outputs as expected.

```py
def recur_partial(text):
    if (len(text) < 1):
        print('')
    else:
        text = text[1:]
        print(text)
        recur_partial(text)
```